# Expected number of fragments generated by a random binary space partition (should be plain combinatorics)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, computer-science, computational-geometry

Let $S$ be a finite ordered set of **non-intersecting** finite line segments in the plane. Let's **randomly shuffle** the elements of $S$ such that each possible permutation of those elements has equal probability of appearance.

Suppose we choose the first element $s_1$ of $S$, **split the plane** by the infinite extension $\ell$ (called a *splitting line*) of $s_1$ into a half-plane $\ell^+$ above and $\ell^-$ below $\ell$ and recursively continue this process for both of the subsets of $S$ induced by $\ell^+$ and $\ell^-$.

The splitting lines may **cut segments into fragments**. The process described above continues until there is only one fragment in the interior of each region induced by the surrounding splitting lines. I hope the following figure will illustrate the result of this process:

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$[image: Binary Space Partitions]

> What's the expected number of fragments generated by this process?

Let's fix some $s\in S$, let $\ell$ be the splitting line induced by $s$ and define $$\operatorname{dist}t:=\begin{cases}\text{number of segments }u\in S\text{ between }s\text{ and }t\text{ with }\ell\cap u\ne\emptyset&\text{, if }\ell\cap t\ne\emptyset\\\infty&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}$$ for $t\in S\setminus\left\{s\right\}$.

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$[image: dist]

Let $$C_n:=\left\{t\in S\setminus\left\{s\right\}:\operatorname{dist}t=n\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N_0$$ (and notice that $|C_n|\le 2$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$, which might be useful).

> Now, let
>
> - $t\in C_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N_0$
> - $u_1,\ldots,u_n\in S\setminus\left\{s\right\}$ be the segments between $s$ and $t$
> - $E$ be the event that $t$ is cut when $\ell$ is added as the next splitting line
>
> I want to show that $$\Pr\left[E\right]\le\frac 1{n+2}\tag 1\;.$$

In order for $E$ to occur, $s$ must come before $t$ and $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ in the random ordering (since $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ shield $t$ from $s$).

I guess I'm thinking way too complicated; my ideas to proceed are as follows:

- There is $1$ possibility to place $s$ at his position $i\in\left\{1,\ldots,N\right\}$ where $N:=|S|$
- There are $N-i$ possibilities to place $t$ at some position $j\in\left\{i+1,\ldots,N\right\}$
- There are $N-i-1$ possibilities to place $u_1$ at some position $k_1\in\left\{i+1,\ldots,N\right\}\setminus\left\{j\right\}$
- $\cdots$
- There are $N-i-n$ possibilities to place $u_n$ at some position $k_n\in\left\{i+1,\ldots,N\right\}\setminus\left\{j,k_1,\ldots,k_{n-1}\right\}$
- There are $\left(\left(i-1\right)+\left(N-\left(\left(i-1\right)+1+1+n\right)\right)\right)!=(N-2-n)!$ possibilities to place the remaining segments at some position

So, there are $$1\cdot\prod_{a=0}^n(N-i-a)\cdot(N-2-n)!=\frac{(N-i)!}{(N-i-n-1)!}(N-2-n)!=:R$$ possible orderings for which $E$ would occur. Since there are $N!$ possible orderings at all, we should have $$\Pr\left[E\right]=\frac{R}{N!}\;.\tag 2$$

Unless the right-hand side  of $(2)$ equals the right-hand side of $(1)$, it seems like I made some mistake. Please note that in either case $(2)$ would be an inequality. This is due to the fact that there might be segments that aren't cut by $\ell$ but whose extension shields $t$ (thus we are concerned with the "worst case").

> So, how can we show $(1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question, "What's the expected number of fragments generated by this process?", is not well-defined unless you specify a distribution for the segments.

In the second part, your inequality ($1$) is right. By symmetry, all of the $n+2$ segments involved have the same probability of being the first among them, so this probability is $\frac1{n+2}$.

In the third part, you have a free variable $i$ which, if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, shouldn't be free but should be summed over from $1$ to $N$. (I haven't given any thought to whether and how this would yield the correct result $\frac1{n+2}$.)

Comment: Why is the first question not well-defined? If the number of fragments generated by the process is $N$, then $N$ is a discrete random variable whose distribution is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: But you didn't say anything about the placement of the segments. Do you want to do this for a particular $S$? Or for a particular distribution for $S$? Or for general $S$? It would seem that the result would depend strongly, and likely in a complicated manner, on $S$?

Comment: $S$ is an arbitrary fixed set of non-intersecting segments. And the algorithm defined by the described process takes such an $S$ as its input. I've asked [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695492/modelling-of-random-variables-involved-in-a-random-binary-space-partition) cause you've confused me with your respond. You can find the algorithm as well as the statement I've asked for in the book [*Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications* by *Mark de Berg*](http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/), below the proof of *Lemma 12.1* .

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I think you should state more clearly in that other question that you want to do this for $S$ an arbitrary fixed set. Asking for a distribution sounds as if there's one particular distribution. You're looking for a distribution that depends on $S$, and I'd expect that dependence to be quite complicated.