# Why do at least half of all random orderings generate a binary space partition of size $n+4n\ln n$ in the random binary space partition algorithm?

Tags: probability, computer-science, expectation, applications, computational-geometry

Let $S$ be a finite ordered set of **non-intersecting** finite line segments in the plane. Let's **randomly shuffle** the elements of $S$ such that each possible permutation of those elements has equal probability of appearance.

Suppose we choose the first element $s_1$ of $S$, **split the plane** by the infinite extension $\ell=\ell(s_1)$ (called a *splitting line*) of $s_1$ into a half-plane $\ell^+$ above and $\ell^-$ below $\ell$ and recursively continue this process for both of the subsets of $S$ induced by $\ell^+$ and $\ell^-$.

The splitting lines may **cut segments into fragments**. The process described above continues until there is only one fragment in the interior of each region induced by the surrounding splitting lines. The result is called **binary space partition**. I hope the following figure will illustrate the result of this process:

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$[image: Binary Space Partitions]

> We can show that $$\Pr\left[t\text{ is cut when }\ell(s)\text{ is added as the next splitting line}\right]\le\frac 1{\operatorname{dist}_st+2}$$ for all $s\in S$ and $t\in S\setminus\left\{s\right\}$ where $$\operatorname{dist}_st:=\begin{cases}\text{# segments }u\in S\text{ between }s\text{ and }t\text{ with }\ell(s)\cap u\ne\emptyset&\text{, if }\ell(s)\cap t\ne\emptyset\\\infty&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}$$ for $s\in S$ and $t\in S\setminus\left\{s\right\}$.

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$[image: dist]

> Thus, $$\operatorname E\left[\text{# cuts generated by }s\right]\le\sum_{t\in S\setminus\left\{s\right\}}\frac 1{\operatorname{dist}_st+2}\le 2\ln n$$ for all $s\in S$ and the expected total number of generated fragments is bounded by $n+2n\ln n$ (since we start with $n$ segments).

**Question**: Why can we conclude that

1. a binary space partition of *size* ($:=$ number of generated fragments) $n+2n\ln n$ **exists**?
2. at least half of all random orderings lead to a binary space partition of size $n+4n\ln n$?

Both statements can be found in [*Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications* by *Mark de Berg*](http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/), below the proof of *Lemma 12.1* and I absolutely don't understand why they are true.

Comment: Please also take note of these related questions: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694427/expected-number-of-fragments-generated-by-a-random-binary-space-partition-shoul) and [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695492/modelling-of-random-variables-involved-in-a-random-binary-space-partition).

Comment: That book isn't freely available, and it seems hard to tell why those statements should be true without the arguments given in the book -- perhaps you should summarize those arguments.

Comment: @joriki That's the problem, the authors state that both statements immediately follow from the result that the expected size ($=$ number of generated fragments) of the binary space partition generated by the algorithm is bounded by $n+2n\ln n$.

Comment: @joriki I don't understand why these statements are true. For example, if we're casting an unbiased dice, the expected outcome is 3.5, but that doesn't mean (of course not) that it's possible to dice a 3.5. But if I'm not terribly wrong, that's the argument they're using.

Comment: It seems likely that you're misunderstanding something. $n+2n\ln n$ isn't a natural number, so there can't be a partition of that size. Also, $n+4n\ln n$ is greater than $n+2n\ln n$, and thus seems to contradict the upper bound in the yellow box. To clear all this up will probably require a copy of the derivation in the book.

Comment: @joriki That's what I've meant in the example (3.5 is not a natural number as well). I'm quite sure that I haven't misunderstood anything. There is no contradiction, since the upper bound is only related to the *expectation*. That doesn't mean that the algorithm cannot generate a higher number of fragments. The algorithm description is [freely available](http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/pseudo.pdf) (Pages 46 and 47). You can find the whole book on github if you're googling "Computational Geometry" + "Algorithms and Applications". You can find the Lemma on page 265 (in the numbering of the book).

Comment: I see. You're right, I'd missed the "expectation" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements in the book are correct if you interpret "of size" to mean "of size at most". Taken literally, they are clearly false.

Comment: Let me try to understand this: The first statement should be: There is a binary space partition (BSP) of $S$ of size at most $n+2n\ln n$. The reason for that is that since the expected size of the BSP generated by the algorithm is at most $n+2n\ln n$, there must be at least one ordering such that the size of the BSP generated by the algorithm is at most $n+2n\ln n$. So far, so good, right? The second statement should be: The algorithm generates a BSP of size at most $n+4n\ln n$ for at least half of all orderings. But *why* is that second statement true?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Yes, so far, so good. The second statement is true because if the algorithm generates a BSP of size greater than $n+4n\ln n$ for more than half of all orderings, the expected number of cuts generated by all segments would be greater than $2n\ln n$ (even if the remaining half contributed zero cuts), which contradicts the fact that the expected number of cuts generated by each segment is at most $2\ln n$.

Comment: I suppose it's easy, but I don't understand why the expected number of cuts generated by all segments would be greater than $2n\ln n$, if the algorithm generates a BSP of size greater than $n+4n\ln n$ for more than half of all orderings. Could you explain this in more detail?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: If the algorithm generates a BSP of size greater than $n+4n\ln n$ for more than half of all orderings, then the number of cuts generated by all segments is greater than $4n\ln n$ for more than half of all orderings (since it's the size of the BSP minus $n$). Then the expected number of cuts generated by all segments is greater than $2n\ln n$ (since it's greater than $4n\ln n$ for half the orderings and at least $0$ for the other half).

Comment: Ah, I see. With this explanation, it turns out to be trivial. Thanks!

Comment: I've got problems to understand why the expected number of recursive invocations (at each step where $S$ is nonempty there are two recursive invocations for the segments $S^\pm:=\left\{s\cap\ell^\pm:s\in S\right\})$ is bounded by the expected number of generated fragments, i.e. by $n+2n\log n$. The following is my explanation and I would appreciate, if you could tell me whether it's correct or not:

Comment: In each invocation with $S$ nonempty, one segment (or call it fragment) is chosen and this fragment is guaranteed to be out of the next recursive invocations. So, with each invocation we "cut out" at least one fragment. Since there are at most $n+2n\log n$ fragments, the number of recursive invocations is bounded by $n+2n\log n$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Yes, you can put it that way. I would have said, each invocation is performed for a specific fragment, and for each fragment at most one invocation is performed, so the number of invocations is bounded by the number of fragments (and hence likewise for their expected values).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "each invocation is performed for a specific fragment"? Is the specific fragment you refer to the one that is chosen as the splitting line? In that case, you would have the problem that each such fragment leads to *two* recursive invocations.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I see; I was counting invocations the wrong way. You're counting them the wrong way, too, though: With your definition above, a single segment would lead to a claimed bound of $1$ but would in fact require two invocations. In the actual algorithm in the book, the recursion is triggered not in each step where $S$ is nonempty but only when $S$ has more than one element. (Sorry, our comments crossed in mid-ether. My previous, now deleted comment wasn't based on the actual algorithm in the book.)

Comment: I don't think that my counting is wrong: Each time the body of the algorithm is entered, the invocation count is increased by one. What I've claimed above is: *Each time the body of the algorithm is entered, one fragment is consumed*. We can ignore the case where $S$ is empty, cause this case could be "hacked" in the algorithm such that a recursive invocation would be avoided. If $S$ contains a single element, this element is consumed (and no further recursive invocations occur).

Comment: If $S$ contains more than one element,  **at least** the first element of $S$ is consumed, cause it's chosen as the splitting line $\ell$, (and two further invocations occur; but that's irrelevant here); in fact all elements of $S$ that overlap with $\ell$ are consumed (but again; that's irrelevant here, cause we're interested in a worst case bound). Thus, the number of invocations is bounded by the number of generated fragments.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Well, if you're allowed to "hack" the algorithm to avoid empty unnecessary invocations, both your count and my count are fine. I meant that your count was wrong with respect to your own definition above ("at each step where $S$ is nonempty there are two recursive invocations for the segments $S^\pm:=\left\{s\cap\ell^\pm:s\in S\right\})$"), since this would lead to two invocations for a single segment.

Comment: You're right, I've excluded the cases where $S$ contains only one element. Thanks for your help, once again.

Comment: You've helped me a lot with this problem so far. Maybe you can help me with my two new related problems too: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700530/why-is-no-analysis-possible-for-the-3d-version-of-the-random-binary-space-partio), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700545/number-of-fragments-into-which-a-fixed-triangle-is-cut-in-the-3d-version-of-the).