# Number of fragments into which a fixed triangle is cut in the 3d version of the binary space partitioning algorithm

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computer-science, computational-geometry

*You can scroll down the question, if you're familiar with the construction of a 3d binary space partition as presented in the book [Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications by Mark de Berg et al.](http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/).*

---

Let

- $S$ be a set of $n$ non-overlapping line segments in the plane
- $\ell(s)$ be the line which contains $s\in S$
- $\ell^+$ and $\ell^-$ be the half-plane above and below of a line $\ell$, respectively

Consider the following algorithm, called $\text{2dBSP}(S)$:

1. Randomly shuffle the elements of $S$ such that each possible permutation of those elements has equal probability of appearance
2. If $S$ contains at most one element, create a tree $T$ with value $S$
3. Otherwise, pick the first element $s_1\in S$ and use $\ell:=\ell(s_1)$ to split the plane:

   - Let $S^\pm:=\left\{s\cap l^\pm:s\in S\right\}$ and $T^\pm:=\text{2dBSP}(S^\pm)$
   - Create a tree $T$ with left subtree $T^-$, right subtree $T^+$ and value $\left\{s\in S:s\subseteq\ell\right\}$
4. Return $T$

> Suppose we have chosen the first few splitting lines. These lines induce a subdivision of the plane whose regions correspond to nodes in the built tree. Consider one such region $r$. There can be segments $s$ in $S$ that cross $r$ completely (i.e. the fragment $f$ of $s$ contained in $f$ doesn't cut any segments inside $r$). Picking $f$ to split $r$ is called a *free split*.

Now, we want to use a set of $n$ non-intersecting triangles $t_1,\ldots, t_n$ in the space instead of $S$. Let $h_i$ be the plane which contains $t_i$. Since we cannot use the literal translation of $\text{2dBSP}$ if we want to be able to analyze the resulting algorithm, we use the following modification, called $\text{3dBSP}$:

1. Randomly shuffle the elements of $S$ such that each possible permutation of those elements has equal probability of appearance
2. **for** $i=1$ **to** $n$:

   - Use $h_i$ to split *every* region where the split is "useful" and make all possible free splits

The definition of a free split can be translated literally to the 3d case.

You can find $\text{3dBSP}$ in the book above *Lemma 12.3*. A $2d$ example of its behavior, in contrast to $\text{2dBSP}$, is shown in the next image

where (a) is the result of $\text{2dBSP}$ and (b) is the result of a $2d$ variant of $\text{3dBSP}$.

---

> **Question**: Let $k\in\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}$ and $N$ be the number of fragments into which $t_k$ is cut. What's the expecation of $N$?

In the book they do the following:

- Let $\ell_i:= h_i\cap h_k$ for $i\in\left\{1,\ldots,k-1\right\}$ be the intersection line of the plane $h_i$ with $h_k$ and $L:=\left\{\ell_1,\ldots, \ell_{k-1}\right\}$
- Let $I:=\left\{i\in\left\{1,\ldots,k-1\right\}:\ell_i\cap t_k\ne\emptyset \right\}$ be the index set of those $\ell_i$ which intersect $t_k$ and $s_i:=\ell_i\cap t_k$ for $i\in I$ be the segment of $\ell_i$ which intersects $t_k$

> Now, they state that $N$ is not the number of faces in the arrangement that $\left\{s_i:i\in I\right\}$ induces on $t_k$. *Why?*

They state the following: Consider the moment where $t_{k-1}$ is treated and assume that $\ell_{k-1}$ intersects $t_k$. The segment $s_{k-1}$ can intersect several faces of the arrangement that $\left\{s_i:i\in I\right\}$ induces on $t_k$. But if such a face $r$ is not incident to one of the edges of $t_k$ (i.e. $r$ is an *interior* face) **then a free split already has been made through this part of $t_k$**.

> Why is that the case? I absolutely don't understand it.

Comment: You've been asking a lot of questions about this algorithm from this book. Even though you made a considerable effort to present the relevant background in the questions and make them self-contained, I found that I often had to consult the book to understand the problem and find the solution. I would suggest, if you ask more of these questions, that you provide the link to the copy of the book on github. It would also provide some context (and allow you to save some space in the exposition of the algorithm) if you link back to earlier questions.

Comment: Where it says "$t_k$ is not the number of faces in the arrangement", I think you meant $N$ instead of $t_k$?

Comment: @joriki I don't think that it's legal to provide a link to a copyright protected book.

Comment: @joriki Yes, in that context $t_k$ should be $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their formulation "through this part" is a bit confusing – what they mean is "using this part". Such an interior face doesn't cut anything in the plane outside of itself because it's shielded on all sides by interior edges, and it doesn't cut anything itself because the triangles are non-intersecting; so the moment it's created it would be used for a free split.

Comment: Let me try to understand this: 1. "The moment **it**'s created" ... You mean a fixed polygonal interior face $r$ which is treated as a fragment, right? 2. I see that the original triangle $t_k$ and $r$ are both treated as fragments, but they are different: The edges of $r$ are surrounded by previously chosen splitting planes and that's not the case for the edges of $t_k$. 3. Let's proceed with caution: You say "an interior face [$r$] doesn't cut anything" ... What do you mean by that? The only objects which might cut some of the fragments are the splitting planes.

Comment: Maybe you've meant that $s_{k-1}$ doesn't cut anything **inside** $r$, but $r$ itself. In that case, I've got the following problem in understanding: What's the difference to the exterior faces? I assume the difference is the following: If $h_{k-1}$ (the plane corresponding to $t_{k-1}$, i.e. the plane corresponding to $\ell_{k-1}$, i.e. the plane corresponding to $s_{k-1}$) is chosen, then $\ell_{k-1}$ (and hence $h_{k-1}$ may exceed the boundary edge(s) of $t_k$, cause they are not surrounded by previously chosen splitting planes.

Comment: **But**: We're only interested in counting the number of fragments into which $t_k$ is cut. And even for an interior face $r$, $r$ is cut into two fragments. **So, why do we not need to count this interior cut**? It's still a cut, isn't it? I don't see how this cut differs from a cut which is made by $s_{k-1}$ on some exterior face.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: No, I don't think it's still a cut -- since $r$ has already been used for a free split, it doesn't get cut. I don't understand why you're talking about whether $\ell_{k-1}$ exceeds the boundary of $t_k$ -- the point is that the split corresponding to $r$ doesn't exceed the boundary of $t_k$ (which is what makes it a free split), whereas if exterior faces are used for splits, they'd have to be extended beyond the boundary and might cut something (and hence might not be free splits -- though they might be -- that possibility doesn't seem to be addressed in the book).

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "$r$ has been used for a free split"? Is "has been used for a free split" a notion for fragments or regions? 2. You say, it "has been used for a free **split**" and hence "doesn't get **cut**". Isn't that a contradiction? Even a free split cuts $r$ into two disconnected halves. 3. Again, you say "if (exterior) faces are used for splits". What do you mean? Only planes induced by fragments are used for splits. So, when $r$ is one fragment before, it's cut into two fragments. Thus, the fragment count is increased by one.

Comment: 4. I assume that in the book they argue that if ℓk−1 cuts an exterior face, this cut cannot be a free split. By definition, a free split is a segment inside a region such that both endpoints lie on a splitting plane. That might or might not be the case for exterior faces, cause their edges might or might not be surrounded by splitting planes. But I assume that this consideration is too complicated. The worst thing which would happen (by ignoring this possibility), is that we count more fragments than necessary. But since we're looking for an upper bound on the fragment count, this is fine.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: 1. It's a notion for fragments. As I understand the algorithm, $r$ is used for a free split as soon as $h(r)$ doesn't cut anything in the region in which $r$ is located. 2. What you write here seems confused to me. A free split by definition doesn't cut anything, and $r$ has been *used for* a free split, which is entirely different from being affected by a split. 3. Perhaps I was slightly abusing the terms -- by "a face is used for a split", I mean "the plane induced by the face is used for a split in the region in which the face is located".

Comment: @0xbadf00d: In the rest of 3., you're again talking about $r$ being cut, which seems to be a misunderstanding. 4. Here again you seem to be talking about faces being cut instead of faces being used for splits. As far as I can tell, you seem to be labouring under a misunderstanding that some cuts between faces don't count because they're free or something like that. Rather, these cuts are never made, because the interior faces are taken out of consideration at an earlier stage when they're used for free splits (not: cut or not cut by free splits).

Comment: Now I think (no offense) that you're confusing something. Please take a look at the last figure in the question. $r$ is one of the grey shaded faces of $t_k$. **We're not interested in any cut which is made by choosing $h(r)$.** So, it's of no interest whether or not $r$ has been chosen previously. Why? Well, cause choosing any of the faces/fragments (i.e. the splitting plane induced by them) of $t_k$ won't cause any cut/fragmentation on/of $t_k$. That's clear, since all these splitting planes are collinear with $t_k$. So, "$h(r)$ doesn't cut anything in the region in which $r$ is located"

Comment: is a triviality, cause any interior face is surrounded by splitting planes which form the region in which this interior face is contained. Now, let's get back to the figure. The whole question is about $s_{k-1}$ (the segment contained in $t_k$ of the intersection line of the planes $h_{k-1}$ and $h_k$).

Comment: The book authors sate that we don't need to count the cut (which you can visually see in the figure) on $r$ (where I assume that $r$ is one of the grey shaded faces which intersects $s_{k-1}$), cause *this* cut/split has already been chosen as a free split. This has nothing to do with any cut/split induced by $h(r)$. Actually, there might be multiple segments $s_i$ with $i<k$ which cut $r$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Also no offense, but *a priori* since currently the proof makes sense to me and not to you, it would seem more likely that you're misunderstanding it than that I am :-) You write: "The book authors state that we don't need to count the cut [...] cause *this* cut/split has already been chosen as a free split." They don't. They write "then a free split already has been made through this part of $t_k$". As I wrote originally in the answer, "through" is an unfortunate choice of word here; but the fact that it's a *free* split shows that this is a split *using* $r$, not *cutting* $r$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: You write: "This has nothing to do with any cut/split induced by $h(r)$." It does. Because of a free split induced by $r$ and thus $h(r)$, $r$ has been taken out of consideration.

Comment: Before diving into details: Why should $h(r)$ have been chosen as a free split? You've said "[$h(r)$] doesn't cut anything in the *plane* outside of *itself*". 1. In which plane? Do you mean "in the *space*" instead? 2. I think I got what you mean "inside itself". If the triangles were allowed to overlap, some other fragment could intersect $r$ and *this* fragment would be cut when choosing $h(r)$, right?

Comment: Let me try to conclude: The reason why $h(r)$ is chosen as a free split is cause choosing $h(r)$ *won't do anything* but taking $r$ out of the set of possible future splitting planes (I've purposely not written "out of consideration"). And now we come to the crucial point: The reason why $r$ is not cut by $s_{k-1}$ is that $r$ is a boundary polygon of a region. It's hard to phrase, but $s_{k-1}$ is the intersection of the infinitely small profile of the plane $h_{k-1}$ with $t_k$. And this infinitely small profile *cannot* break through a boundary polygon of a region. What do you think?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: These things are rigorously defined in the book. On p. $261$, $h^+$ and $h^-$ are defined using strict inequalities, i.e. they're the open half-spaces defined by the plane. Thus $r$ itself is not part of the regions passed as arguments in the recursive calls that are made when $r$ induces a free split. Regarding the rest of what you wrote, I think the main point is that $r$ necessarily induces a free split because there's nothing it could cut (it's basically in the position of $f$ in the 2D picture), whereas the exterior faces may or may not induce free splits.

Comment: Is anything of my last two comments wrong or do you agree with me?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Not exactly wrong, but I don't agree with the "It's hard to phrase" part -- I think it's quite clear-cut, if you'll excuse the pun :-) There's no need to talk about infinitely small profiles. The half-spaces don't include the planes, so once $r$ induces a free split, it can no longer be cut. Also I didn't understand why you think that "doesn't cut anything in the space" would be clearer than "... in the plane", but I don't see anything explicitly wrong there.

Comment: You're right, what I've written is correct, but too complicated. The simplest argument is the one you've mentioned. I thought you mean something special when you've said "doesn't cut anything in the plane", but I guess you've meant "doesn't cut anything" at all.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Sorry, I hit the "discussion to chat" link by accident :-)

Comment: I've resisted to accept the offer, so it didn't hurt ;) Thanks for your patience. I guess I've got it now.